# getting a file name from a folder into page using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

if it's possible, can some one please help me with this i made Youtube for example. as you see in this PLNKR LINK http://plnkr.co/edit/44EQKSjP3Gl566wczKL6?p=preview

for example "embed" is my folder and in that "embed" folder i have files with name "p9zdCra9gCE" "QrMOu4GU3uU"

as you see them in here

```
<div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="QrMOu4GU3uU">video 2</div>
```

if it's possible i want it like, when ever i add a file like, "p9zdCra9gCE.html" or "QrMOu4GU3uU.html" in folder "embed", and it will be automatically on index page next to other video buttons to become like this

```
<div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="QrMOu4GU3uU">video 2</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="AnotherFile">video 3</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="AnotherFile">video 4</div>
<div class="ytid" data-str="AnotherFile">video 5</div>
```

i have tried this in youtube and it seems to work but i want some how to put file name in here video 1 replace it with "p9zdCra9gCE" and remove file extension to become "p9zdCra9gCE" instead of "p9zdCra9gCE.html" in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3UazvF-zF4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove .html part with str_replace() function like this:

```
$file = 'p9zdCra9gCE.html';
echo str_replace('.html', '', $file);
```

Where $file is the name of the file you want to "edit", then, in str_replace function first argument is part you wish to replace, second is what you want to replace it with and third is where you want to replace it. In this case you want to replace '.html' with empty string, "". You can read more about str_replace() on official php docs - http://php.net/str_replace

EDIT:

You can use this in combination with function from video like this:

```
$id = 1;
foreach (glob('*.html') as $file) {
    $file = str_replace('embed/', '', $file);
    $file = str_replace('.html', '', $file); ?>
    <div class="ytid" data-str="<?php echo $file; ?>">video <?php echo $id++ ?></div>
<?php }
```

Store video files only in one directory and no other files should be stored there otherwise you'll fetch them with `glob()` as well as long as they have .html as file extension. Modify path of `glob()` to point to that directory like this: `glob('embed/*.html')`

Comment: thanks. 1- in your code i don't see you showed the folder which there's files. 2- i want to add divs like this automatically for example when ever i add file in folder with name "p9zdCra9gCE.html" and it will be add by itself on index page like this <div class="ytid" data-str="p9zdCra9gCE">video 1</div>

Comment: I thought you had that sorted out by watching that video. I edited my answer to include how to have it automatically generate divs and fill information accordingly. Important is that you have all videos in separate folder since you'll store every file from that directory in an array that you'll loop through, so if you have index.html in that folder, a div with `data-str="index"` will be created. To avoid that just store all files in another directory and point to that directory like this: `glob('directory/*.html')`

Comment: thank you sir it's alost worked but i have 1 problems i will be glag if you can fix them for me. 1- all buttons that is generated, all of them have name "video", "video", "video". is there way some how it will become like, "video 1", "video 2", "video 3" ? and 2nd problem is my index and videos files are not in ame folder. so it makes problem for links for example when i click on video it will make the link to be like, https://www.youtube.com/embed/embed/p9zdCra9gCE as you see same "embed" but twice in the link

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `echo` before `$id++`, if you add it it should show video 1, video 2, video 3... As for link, its easy fix, I don't usually use `glob()` so I forgot about it's output, just add `str_replace()` for embed/. I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: thank you sir the code worked but i get it like this i don't know why look http://s10.postimg.org/k7qn9nfcp/testphp.png

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change php closure tag when I edited code. Gonna edit the answer now

Comment: thank you sir. but it's not generating video buttons depending on number of files in embed folder. it generates button from 1-9 by it self

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Can you screenshot your code and then the problem?

Comment: sir here's screenshot http://goo.gl/hXEZsG and as you see in screenshot i pointed to get file name from bbm folder (bbm is instead of embed) and it gets name of files from root folder and directory is bbm and i get error that's when you click on one of buttons. and here's my full code that is on page http://plnkr.co/edit/Sqna5UAOiMHyTZ8UxUjU?p=preview (plnkr may don't allow php don't know) but you can test it on php page.

notes(that files you see in screenshot upcoming.html, main.html, dmca.html. these all are in root directory i don't want to pint at it

Comment: You didn't change `glob()` function to look inside your directory. Change `glob('*.html')` to `glob('bbm/*.html')` or whatever is the name of directory you store video files in.

Comment: you are a real master sir you did. you are second person i meet that he have this much experience and we are your students we learn from you. thanks a lot sir. this is one little problem sir i don't think it's big deal look at this screenshot http://goo.gl/FaFdVR when page loaded that link must be same link like here http://goo.gl/vnm1bU it was like that but don't know what changed in that

Comment: You want to add chan1-link to the url?

Comment: yes in that text are there must be that chan1-link it's like default link as you see it in video 1 button. before you click button video you see there's wrong url in that text are. but when you click on button video 1 it will change to correct one. before, it was like that when page loaded there's the correct url

Comment: Change `$file = str_replace('bbm/', '', $file);` to `$file = str_replace('bbm/', 'chan1-link', $file);`

Comment: no sir when page loaded it will still the same and when click on button it will make it like this http://goo.gl/vdwz6Y but i think it's something from my javascript code as you see in bottom of page here http://plnkr.co/edit/Sqna5UAOiMHyTZ8UxUjU?p=preview because why it keep restoring old link i mean like old way i was doing in storing links. it was just changing number 1 in the link not whole chan1-link1

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much javascript so I can't help you there

Comment: ok sir. thanks for all help you did you for me that i needed. i will ask some one who made this javascript code for me he may know. i really appreciate your help. thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help

Comment: hey sir, i am not able to open another question i just wanted to ask you something, is it possible to create search box for website using php and javascript only? i mean no database needed 

for example on index.php i have search box and i have results.php that will bring and show the search results using php or javascript ?

Comment: Not sure, it should be possible with javascript if you store all data in array or something and then have search functionality that will search inside that array and show results accordingly, but like I said, I don't have much experience with javascript so I can't help you there, but it should be possible with javascript and not that hard to implement. PHP is bad option for that since it's not dynamic language like javascript